# Find distinct, duplicate values in SQL and show them all

Tags: mysql, sql, duplicates

I've got a database of several datasets with latitude and longitude coordinates as well as corresponding data on the weather.
I've tried this query:

```
SELECT distinct `lat`,`lon` 
FROM weatherdata 
WHERE `maxtemp`=0 AND `mintemp`=0 AND `humidity`=0 AND `windspeed`=0
HAVING COUNT(*)>300
```

in order to find coordinates where all the weather data is set to "0" in over 300 datasets. However, this only displays one coordinate set and I know for a fact that there are way more.
What is the correct way of doing so?

Comment: Remove  DISTINCT keyword from your query

Comment: @Oscar, thanks, but didn't help as to it still shows only one result.

Comment: Remove `distinct` AND add `GROUP BY lat, lon` after your WHERE clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following;

```
SELECT distinct `lat`,`lon` 
FROM (Select count(*) as c, `lat`,`lon` from weatherdata 
   WHERE `maxtemp`=0 AND `mintemp`=0 AND `humidity`=0 AND `windspeed`=0 
   GROUP BY `lat`, `lon` having c > 300)
```

Comment: Thanks, I see what you're trying to do there, gives me a syntax error at `where c > 300) LIMIT 0, 25` though.

Comment: Why do you have "Limit 0,25" at the end of your query?

Comment: I changed it to use having - try this version.